# How to see chat titles in ChatGPT history?

Tags: chatgpt

They made ChatGPT to give title to each chat session and store them in history. Unfortunately, they forgot to give an ability to see these titles, since they are truncated and there is no way to make left pane wider.

Am I missing something?

Example:

[image]

How to know, what "Unmonting directory not w" stands for?

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways I've found:

- Narrow your window, increasing the size of the sidebar
- Click on the the chat to load it

  - Click on the pencil, showing all the text in a scrollable input field
  - OR look at the top bar (narrow mode only)
- Select the text by holding down the left mouse button and the relevant key (<kbd>alt</kbd> on Windows or <kbd>option</kbd> on Mac) and dragging the mouse, which allows you to select text without clicking on the link. From here you have several options, but the easiest would be to drag the text into the address bar so you can see it all. You could copy and paste into another document. Right clicking on my selection (Mac) also showed me the full text.